# Is there a way to make a graphic of player's movement in Unity?

Tags: unity

I want to verify the graph of the y-position of my player in function of time. Is there a easy way to accomplish it in unity?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. More information is needed. Try saving the positions in a data structure for starters. Use the fixedUpdate event for consistent results.

Comment: Can you describe the output you want to generate in more detail? What should it look like, or what information should it convey?

Comment: I was expecting something like, jumping and existing a pre-defined tool that would generate a graphic y-position versus time, for example, for selected interval. But I will search a way through data structures too

Comment: Do you want to generate this analytically based on the math of your movement functions? Or empirically, where you record data points observed during play like Alexus suggests? Have you tried using Gizmos for the visualization?

Comment: Empirically. I could visualize the data through Alexus suggestion, It Worked well.  I will see gizmoz then, haven't used this tool.

Comment: If you solved your problem, don't forget to post your solution as an answer below.